# Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What's the meaning of `~>` version requirement in gem specs?

```
hanna-0.1.12 depends on [haml (~> 2.2.8)]
```

Comment: or [twiddle-wakka](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint)

Comment: +1 @SuckerForMayhem , "twiddle-wakka" is funnier. New link: http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint -- which itself links to https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem Twiddle-wakka sounds like some kind of legendary beast like the chupacabra. This has been my contribution to the topic. You're welcome society.

Comment: thx for updated links @TheRedPea

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The RubyGems manual calls this a
[pessimistic version constraint](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns#pessimistic_version_constraint).

Assume you have specified an n-part version number, e.g. `1.3` (2-part) or
`3.5.6.2` (4-part) as the constraint. Then, in order to fulfill the constraint,
a version number must satisfy both of the following conditions

1. The first n-1 parts of the version number must be identical to the first n-1
   parts of the constraint
   (e.g. `1.x` or `3.5.6.x` match, but `0.x` or `3.5.7.x` don't) **and**
2. The last part of the version number must be greater than or equal to the last
   part of the constraint
   (e.g. `1.9999` and `3.5.6.2` match, but `1.2` or `3.5.6.1` don't).

In other words

```
~> x1.x2.x3. … .xn-2.xn-1.xn
```

matches

```
x1.x2.x3. … .xn-2.xn-1.y, y >= xn
```

The reason this is called a "pessimistic" constraint, and also the use case for
it, is that when you just say `> x.y.z`, you are being optimistic: you assume
that from here on out, until all eternity, the API will never ever change. This
is of course a pretty bold assumption. However, most projects have rules about
when they are allowed to
[break backwards compatibility](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns#semantic_versioning),
and how they have to change their version number when they *do* break backwards
compatibility. You can encode those version numbering rules using a pessimistic
constraint, and thus you can be sure that your code will always continue to work
(assuming that the author of the other project actually adheres to his own
rules, which unfortunately isn't always the case).

Comment: In other words: ~> means it will only allow that specific version, and newer sub-versions in the last decimal.

Answer (score 26):

In other words, you can use this symbol to keep your gem updated with all the minor updates and avoid making a major update that can break your app.

For example "~> 1.2" will update your gem to 1.3 (if such a version is released) but it won’t update it to 2.0

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete. It is important to mention that the number of parts in the version number is relevant. For instance, "~> 1.2.0" will not update the gem to 1.3 – but it would rather update it to a version >= 1.2.0 and < 1.3.0

Answer (score 19):

I think [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) best sum this up:

> The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. ~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and < 3.0. ~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I'm happy that the accepted answer explains this in more detail. This example-based explanation doesn't really help me understand what the operator means.

Answer (score -1):

It matches any version that has the same major / minor part. This means in this case that haml ~> 2.2.8 will match any 2.2.x version.

This can be used to make sure that an API breaking change in a new gem, doesn't result in depending on that newly but changed gem that would break hanna in this case.

Comment: This is not incorrect, but it is incomplete. It is important to undersatnd the difference between `~> 2.0` and `~> 2.0.0` -- the former matches 2.0, 2.1, 2.2.7, and everything else up to (but not including) 3.0. The latter matches 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.999, and everything else up to (but not including) 2.1.

Comment: @James A. Rosen: Also, `~> 2.2.8` will *not* match "any 2.2.x" version as the answer claims, but only 2.2.x versions with x ≥ 8. IOW: the answer is at best even more incomplete, bordering on incorrect and definitely misleading.