# What does the ~> operator mean?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of ~> in version requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-in-version-requirement)

I often stumble upon the ~> operator.

eg.

```
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.5.2'
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Your title and the first line of the question is different from the example! Which operator is your question about? My answer is about the ~> operator used in gem dependencies.

Comment: @Jörg: Did you do a manual search? How do people do that to find duplicates?

Comment: In this particular case, I knew that I a) had answered the question myself and b) used the words *pessimistic version constraint* in the answer, so I simply searched for `user:me [ruby] pessimistic` in the search box. In the more general case, I simply read (or at least skim) every Ruby question on StackOverflow, so I have at least briefly glimpsed at every single one of the 13000 question at least once, and I remember which ones have already been asked and answered.

Comment: The problem is that StackOverflow's search doesn't allow you to search for `~>` (or `=~`, `||`, `&&`, `===`, `||=`, `&&=`, which are other examples of questions that get repeated over and over again), so the only way to find them, is to know what they are called, which basically means that in order to find an answer to your question you already have to know the answer to your question. Unfortunately, fixing the search seems to be a rather low priority. That's why it is important to flag and close these questions in order to consolidate the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [pessimistic version constraint](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74). It matches a gem version by dropping the last digit and comparing equality. For example, `~> 0.5.2` would match version 0.5.2 or 0.5.3, but not 0.5 or 0.6. It's basically equivalent to a constraint of `>= 0.5.2, < 0.6`.

Comment: It would appear that the link is broken. Here is a more up to date page on this idea. http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/ Just search for pessimistic version control in document to find it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It means that any version >= 0.5.2 and < 0.6.0

Yehuda Katz recently wrote about this - http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/21/using-considered-harmful-or-whats-wrong-with/