# What does the ~> symbol mean in a bundler Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

What does the `->` mean next to a version number in a Gemfile?

For example:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
```

Comment: So it is, but a decent search didn't find that question.

Comment: No sweat! There is plenty of space on Interwebs. A little duplication is rather good. :)

Comment: While we're mentioning duplicates, here's the oldest question that it's a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3414337

Answer (score 104, accepted):

From the bundler website:

> The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example:
>   `'~> 2.0.3'`   is identical to `'>= 2.0.3`' and `'< 2.1.'` 
>   `'~> 2.1'`     is identical to `'>= 2.1'`    and `'< 3.0'`. 
>   `'~> 2.2.beta'` will match prerelease versions like `'2.2.beta.12'`.

See https://bundler.io/gemfile.html and http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint

Comment: Yes, you're right and I was way too fast with my answer and was in editing already, sorry!

Comment: Okay, I had been reading the gemfile manual which didn't seem to have that info. Should have just stuck to the pretty pages!

Answer (score 23):

You usually use this to tell bundler that it's ok to install some minor updates (last digit specified can vary) but not to install some major update.

SO

`~> 2.0.3` means `>= 2.0.3` ∩ `< 2.1`

and

`~> 2.1` means `>= 2.1` ∩ `< 3.0`

Read more at https://bundler.io/gemfile.html