# feedzirra windows latest curb version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, curb, feedzirra

I am trying to install `feedzirra` but I am running into trouble.

When I install Feedzirra, it looks for `curb (0.7.18)`.

I followed the instructions to install curb on windows

```
>gem install curb -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw
32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/include
Fetching: curb-0.8.4.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/b
in --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/include'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed curb-0.8.4
Installing ri documentation for curb-0.8.4
1 gem installed
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall feedzirra, it did not help as I get the following message

```
Installing curb (0.7.18)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/curb-0.7.18 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.7.
18/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing curb (0.7.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install curb -v '0.7.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How do I force feedzirra to use the latest version of curb? or How to install curb (0.7.18) version only?

Comment: Are you using Bundler?

Comment: Yes, I used Feedzirra in Rails Application.

Comment: +1 for use of `/bin` instead of `/lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `-v 0.7.18` after `gem install curb`:

```
>gem install curb -v 0.7.18 -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/include
```

The latest [Feedzirra](http://rubygems.org/gems/feedzirra) has a `curb ~> 0.7.15` as a dependency, so `curb-0.8.4` won't be suitable - here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699949/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-a-bundler-gemfile) referring to the [bundler site](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html).

Also if you're using something like `RVM` (if I remember correctly there's a nearly similar utility for windows called `pik`) then ensure that you're installing gems to the gemset used  by your application.