# Gem update issue with ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, unicorn

I was trying to update my ruby 1.9.3 to 2.2.2, and when i test in local that all was working fine, but when i try to push to heroku i got the raindrops issue version and then i update the rain drops by command

```
bundle update raindrops
```

but after that when i was checking this Gemfile.lock it shows

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
  raindrops (0.17.0)
unicorn (4.6.3)
  kgio (~> 2.6)
  rack
  raindrops (~> 0.7)
```

Here the raindrops under the unicorn didn't change, the other one only changed, it push successfully, will it be make any issue for unicorn at any time in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read you `Gemfile.lock` like this:

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
  raindrops (0.17.0)     # <- This is the installed version (0.17.0 is the latest)
unicorn (4.6.3)
  kgio (~> 2.6)
  rack
  raindrops (~> 0.7)     # <- This is the version unicorn depends on
```

You have the latest version of that gem installed (see [`raindrops`](https://rubygems.org/gems/raindrops)  page on RubyGems). `unicorn` itself depends on a `raindrops` version between `0.7` and `< 1.0`, the version `0.17.0` fulfills this requirements.

All good!

Comment: thanks, also how can i know this statement "unicorn itself depends on a raindrops version between 0.7 and < 1.0, the version 0.17.0  fulfills"

Comment: Got it that meaning thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699949/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-a-bundler-gemfile

Comment: `~>` is called a the [pessimistic operator](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator).