# what does ~> mean in gemspec dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-tilde-greater-than-in-version-requirement)

I see something like this a lot in gemspecs:

```
s.add_dependency 'some_gem', '~> 1.5.0'
```

What does ~> mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [gembundler](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html)

```
The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. 
~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. 
~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and < 3.0. 
~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.
```