# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to install a new gem into a rails app and regardless of whether I add or remove a gem from the Gemfile, when I run `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.3.5)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

I am confused, because `~> 1.0.0` means that I have to have a version of `bundler` equal to or greater than 1.0.0 but less than 2.x.x. I'm fulfilling this requirement, so why is it failing?

Just to add, if I leave the Gemfile as is, `bundle install` works just fine.

**UPDATE**

Clearly, I misunderstood the ~> symbol. You can look at the checked answer below for an explanation, or an even more in depth one at [Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-tilde-greater-than-in-version-requirement)

Comment: There's still the same issue popping up nowadays, here's a concrete solution when you can't update the application to use a newer bundler version:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `~> 1.0.0` is equal to `>= 1.0.0` && `< 1.1`, so 1.3.5 doesn't match. You need another bundler version.