# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": In Gemfile:

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, jekyll

I'm making GitHub blog page with Jekyll. I've failed like numerous times and just forked new one and followed README on the repository.

It's https://github.com/janczizikow/sleek/blob/master/README.md
and I tried to run  inside the directory(master) but this msg keeps coming out.

I tried 'gem install bundler' 'gem cleanup' and similar solutions on the internet but still can't fix it. I get that I need another version which is lower one, then how can I remove the current one and install the version I need?

I've never used Ruby so I'm SO lost. A little advice will mean a lot.

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 1.12) x64-mingw32

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.12)' in any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation
```

Answer (score 5):

Version 2.0.2 comes from `gem install bundler`, but the project uses bundler version 1.12.

To fix your issue run

1. `gem install bundler -v 1.12`
2. `bundle _1.12_ install`

To start Jekyll run `jekyll serve` or `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but even after I did 'gem install bundler -v 1.12', it still shows the same msg. maybe should I completely remove the latest version on my windows? or what should I do?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to run `bundle _1.12_ install ` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! after following your answer, `bundle install` worked. But then entered `npm install`, it says `gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];`

Comment: No idea, your question was related to ruby and bundler. Sorry. Somehow related to note gyp but I have no clue at all.

Comment: I googled ... found this: Rebuilding native node modules requires node-gyp, which requires Python 2. Install Python 2 and make sure it's first in %PATH% (i.e., before Python 2.7 that you have installed) so node-gyp can find it.