# How to get old Jekyll site working on localhost

Tags: jekyll, bundler

Several years ago, I built a site in Jekyll. We're redoing the site, so I needed to set up a new folder. I used rbenv to get an updated Ruby version (3.0), and I've got the new Jekyll site up and running on localhost.

However, I can no longer access my old Jekyll site (I think I may have updated my gems globally instead of locally - oops!). Typing `jekyll serve` into the terminal tells me that I'm missing bundler 1.12.5, as required by my gemfile.

Trying to install that bundler returns the following:

> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)".

My local version of Ruby is 2.0.
The error is the same under 2.0 and 3.0.
Gem version: 2.0.14.

Installing webrick did not resolve the problem, and according to the troubleshooting guide on [this page](https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#ssl-and-tls-protocol-versions), it's not an SSL cert or TLS issue (but I could be wrong on that).

I could really use some help in getting the old site running on my localhost again! Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to run the automated SSL check described on the page you've linked (`curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby`)? To  run bundler 1.12 you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170296/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler-in-gemfile/57172655#57172655

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

Option 1:

Delete your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle` (If that gives you errors try `bundle install && bundle update`). This will build the old site with the newest version of the Gems.

Option 2:

Use a Ruby version manager (I like rbenv). Install the old Ruby version in the project directory (using a `.ruby-version` file).

Comment: Thank you! Weirdly enough, I did the hackiest thing imaginable - I had Jekyll working on a new site, and I simply replaced the old gemfile with the new one, and that worked, with a few errors. I expect I could have followed your suggestions as well! :)