# Unable to activate faraday_middleware-0.9.0 // Gem::LoadError // trying to run the pocket-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to run the pocket-ruby gem and after I clone the repo and bundle, it raises this error:

```
Unable to activate faraday_middleware-0.9.0, because faraday-0.9.0 conflicts with faraday
(< 0.9, >= 0.7.4)
```

The gemspecfile for the pocket-ruby gem looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../lib/pocket/version', __FILE__)

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
 s.add_development_dependency('sinatra', '~> 1.3.3')
 s.add_development_dependency('multi_xml')

 s.add_runtime_dependency('faraday', ['>= 0.7', '< 0.9'])
 s.add_runtime_dependency('faraday_middleware', '~> 0.8')

 s.add_runtime_dependency('multi_json', '>= 1.0.3', '~> 1.0')
 s.add_runtime_dependency('hashie',  '>= 0.4.0')
 s.authors = ["Turadg Aleahmad","Jason Ng PT"]
 s.description = %q{A Ruby wrapper for the Pocket API v3 (Add, Modify and Retrieve)}
 s.email = ['turadg@aleahmad.net',"me@jasonngpt.com"]
 s.executables = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
 s.files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
 s.homepage = 'https://github.com/turadg/pocket-ruby'
 s.name = 'pocket-ruby'
 s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
 s.require_paths = ['lib']
 s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new('>= 1.3.6') 
 if s.respond_to?    :required_rubygems_version=
 s.rubyforge_project = s.name
 s.summary = %q{Ruby wrapper for the Pocket API v3}
 s.test_files = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
 s.version = Pocket::VERSION
end
```

I messed around with changing the versions on the two dependencies in question but didn't have any luck, since I guess I am not entirely sure what the error is saying.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict between the two version specifiers - `~> 0.8` means "any version of the form 0.x", but `< 0.9` means that `0.9` is not actually allowed.

You'll need to determine which of these need to change - maybe `~> 0.8` should really be `~> 0.8.0`, which would specify "any version of the form 0.8.x".

More info on the pessimistic constraint operator (`~>`) here:

[Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-tilde-greater-than-in-version-requirement)