# Forcing older version of dependent gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

The app I am developing has suddenly stopped deploying to Heroku, with the error:

```
remote:        Gem::InstallError: execjs requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.                        
remote:        An error occurred while installing execjs (2.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.  
remote:        Make sure that `gem install execjs -v '2.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.         
remote:  !                                                                                      
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.                                              
remote:  !                                                                                      
remote:                                                                                         
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Ruby 2.0 is not a viable option for me (I have no choice but develop on MS Windows, and too much Ruby 2.0 stuff didn't work for Windows last time I looked), but I don't think I need execjs -v2.5.1. I don't call it up explicitly in my gemfile, and if I run `gem dependency execjs --reverse-dependencies` I get:

```
Gem execjs-1.4.0                            
  multi_json (~> 1.0)                       
  rake (>= 0, development)                  
  Used by                                   
    coffee-script-2.3.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    coffee-script-2.2.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    sprockets-2.12.3 (execjs (~> 1.0, develo
    sprockets-2.11.0 (execjs (~> 1.0, develo
    sprockets-2.1.3 (execjs (~> 1.0, develop
    uglifier-2.5.3 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      
    uglifier-1.2.6 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      

Gem execjs-2.2.1                            
  rake (>= 0, development)                  
  Used by                                   
    coffee-script-2.3.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    coffee-script-2.2.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    uglifier-2.5.3 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      
    uglifier-1.2.6 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      

Gem execjs-2.2.2                            
  rake (>= 0, development)                  
  Used by                                   
    coffee-script-2.3.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    coffee-script-2.2.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    uglifier-2.5.3 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      
    uglifier-1.2.6 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      

Gem execjs-2.3.0                            
  rake (>= 0, development)                  
  Used by                                   
    coffee-script-2.3.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    coffee-script-2.2.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    uglifier-2.5.3 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      
    uglifier-1.2.6 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      

Gem execjs-2.4.0                            
  rake (>= 0, development)                  
  Used by                                   
    coffee-script-2.3.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    coffee-script-2.2.0 (execjs (>= 0))     
    uglifier-2.5.3 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))      
    uglifier-1.2.6 (execjs (>= 0.3.0))
```

It looks as if I don't need anything later than v2.4.0 (am I reading that correctly?) but how do I tell my gems to use an old version, not the latest?

Comment: Add that gem in your gemfile by specifying the required version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try locking your execjs version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'execjs', '2.4.0'
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but thinking back I don't think I checked it in, so Heroku wouldn't have seen it. Thanks.

Comment: `2.5.0` should also be ok with Ruby versions `< 2.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the gem version in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.3.4"
```

or (specific version)

```
gem "haml-rails", "0.3.4"
```

For more information, click here:
[Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-tilde-greater-than-in-version-requirement)