# "Could not find activesupport" when 3 versions installed

Tags: ruby

I'm just trying to use the simple [`career_builder` gem](https://github.com/mguterl/career_builder) and just get it imported by running the simple script:

```
require 'career_builder'

puts 'Hello world!'
```

and yet get the following error: `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (~> 2.3.5) - did find: [activesupport-4.2.1,activesupport-3.1.12,activesupport-3.0.3] (Gem::LoadError)`

I installed the gem with `gem install career_builder` and ran `bundle install` and even updated `activesupport` to the most recent version, but for some reason, the program can't find the newer version of `activesupport`. Does the gem require version `2.3.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/

The `~>`or 'twiddle-waka' is a ruby gems shortcut to specify the earliest version of the gem you can use without letting you go up to the next major release.

Your gem is being a bit unorthodox and also specifying a patch level.
So the gem_specification you're working with (`activesupport' (~> 2.3.5)`) really means minimum version of 2.3.5 maximum of the last patch released before 2.4.0.

The activesupport versions you have installed are all for subsequent major releases and won't work. Install something between 2.3.5 and 2.4.0 and you should be good to go.

Comment: Edited. Sometimes I forget that versions aren't real decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does require Active Support version >= 2.3.5 and < 2.4.0. All of your Active Support versions are > 2.4.0.

`~>` is called the spermy operator. See [Meaning of tilde-greater-than (~>) in version requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414337/meaning-of-tilde-greater-than-in-version-requirement)

The gem has not been updated in 4 years, so it uses Rails 2.

FWIW, I don't think you'll have much luck getting it to work, so you may want to find a similar gem that works with Rails 4 and has been updated within the last few months.

Comment: I was afraid I'd run into issues with the old gem, but it was the best thing I could find for an interface with CareerBuilder's API. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, I see it is the only gem for Career Builder. Since it is a REST API, you may want to use an HTTP client gem. I have used HTTParty and would recommend it. See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients for other HTTP client gems.

Comment: I'll be sure to take a look at that as well as HTTP clients in Python. Thanks again for the help.